# How to determine which hardware I'm running on in MacOSX

Tags: c++, macos, hardware

I've been writing a piece of code which contains parts that should be executed only when running on a Macbook, Macbook Pro or a MacBook Air.

So far I'm using Targetconditionals.h, however I can only verify that I'm not running on a mobile using this strategy, and my code keeps being executed on iMac and Mac Mini.

Do you have guys any hint about how to get some specific information that would match only if the program is running in a Macbook, Macbook Pro or a Macbook Air?

Comment: Strange limitation to build into software. How do you plan on handling Hackintosh?

Comment: @rubenvb or any virtual machine for that matter. I don't know that it would make sense from Apple's perspective to include anywhere in their Operating System the model of the computer running it. I **do** know though, that Apple has a page online where you can enter a serial number and get the computer model. Perhaps you could leverage that?

Comment: @Josh Unfortunately I'm working with CoreAudio and this issue is related to the way the laptops are built and where devices are placed. It could be a hardware component or property which is specific to Apple laptops, or some field which could be platform specific for those. I'm not sure if I could use what you propose in this particular case.

Comment: @pabloxrl I know AppleScript has access to the **System Information** Utility's information. You could look into using `osascript` from the command line.

Comment: @pabloxrl why not just try accessing the hardware or property and bail out if it fails? No need to add arbitrary checks to enforce your assumptions that my become invalid in the future.

Comment: @rubenvb The issue for me is that I couldn't come up with any property or piece of hardware that would make the MacBooks distinct yet. If you have any hint that would be nice.

Comment: @pabloxrl Then you clearly do not need to make the distinction; if your code works regardless, there is no reason to know exactly which is which, unless you want to expressly print out "MacBook", "MacBook Pro", or "MacBook Air". Again: you can do runtime checking and fall back to another method if some function fails. That is much more error proof than manually selecting on currently released models and distinctions.

Comment: @rubenvb Thank you, but you're not answering my question.

Comment: @pabloxrl right, I'm writing a comment in the hope of convincing you you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here finally I got something that may be a hint for others in a similar situation:

```
#include <string>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>


bool isMacBook()
{
    size_t len = 0;
    ::sysctlbyname("hw.model", nullptr, &len, nullptr, 0);
    std::string model(len, '\0');
    ::sysctlbyname("hw.model", const_cast<char *>(model.data()), &len, nullptr, 0);
    return model.find("MacBook") != std::string::npos;
}
```

I don't consider it a full fix, but seems to me it can provide useful info.